# How to change the lowest and highest screen brightness in Android?

Tags: stock-android, screen-brightness

Is there any way to reduce the lowest and highest screen brightness settings by editing the build.prop file in Android? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change/set the following parameters in the build.prop to set the brightness.

```
ro.lcd_min_brightness=50
ro.lcd_brightness=255
```

The above is an example. The first set the minimum.

The range is from 1 to 255. 1 being the minimum level that can be set while 255 is the maximum.

Comment: Using the above lines, can I set the max brightness to more than 255? And how to set the min brightness to below 0?

Comment: See the edit for details.

Comment: tried on Oneplus 5T and OxygenOS 9.0.8, does not work. :/